# When I use Time.deltaTime, it stops my function from working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my code whene I want to move a character from right or left, the code works but unfortunately after 2 seconds the character stops and when I used Time.deltaTime, my character no longer moves. Do you have any ideas? the console displays messages well

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveUpDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float moveSpeed;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        moveSpeed = 10f;
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("il vas a droite");
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * -moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    public void StopMoving()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        Debug.Log("il bouge plus");
    }

   
}
```

Comment: A `velocity` already **is** a frame rate independent movement per second -> no need to `Time.deltaTime` it just makes it extremely slow

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the `Time.deltaTime`.

You're directly assigning the velocity to some value so you don't need the `Time.deltaTime`.

if you want to gradually add some velocity to an object inside the update function that's when you need the `Time.deltaTime`.

for Example;

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.left * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

also you can check this thread;

https://forum.unity.com/threads/velocity-time-deltatime.91518/